# Which http request method should I use in Laravel routes?

Tags: laravel, routes, httprequest

I'm developing a rest api in Laravel 5.7. I know how to make api controllers and how to define appropriate api resource routes referring to corresponding methods in the controller like below:

```
Route::apiResource('platforms', 'PlatformController');
```

However, I'm not sure which HTTP request method should I use when I'm trying to define some other methods in my controller rather than the five restful controller methods (index, store, show, update and delete). For example, when in the controller I'm defining a function for toggling a Boolean value in database, either 'Get', 'Post' or 'put' method does works. So, which one is the best choice?

Comment: Your question will most likely attract opinionated answer. But have you considered 'PUT' because as I can see, you're just _updating_ a boolean value in the database?

Comment: Well, that would be okay isn't it? Otherwise you can use _PATCH_. Another option is just create a new PUT route that just does that which would be the most neutral options. GET verb is a no no.

Comment: I made a mistake in posting previous comment. Yes, there is a new route for toggling action which is irrelevant to the request validation I formed. So I'll use PUT or Patch in the new route. Thank you so much. But the last question is that is there a difference between Put and Patch in this specific situation (toggle a status)?

Comment: Just a note, I realised your question is resolved. It will do well to either check the answers given already or post the solution to your question so others find it helpful in the future.

As for your question, however, PATCH and PUT has been debated but, I'd rather say consistency is more important than _rightness_ in situation like this. PUT would need the full but modified object being updated, PATCH takes a part of the object to update. So, its up to you to chose... See: https://www.google.com/search?q=patch+request&oq=patch+request

Comment: Thank you so much for your guide. It was so helpful. Actually, as I've just signed up, I'm not able to rate answers...

Answer (score 2):

Here the basic route descriptions 
you can know more from

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing

```
┌────────┬─────────┬──────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ HTTP   │ CRUD    │ ENTIRE COLLECTION (e.g /USERS)   │ SPECIFIC ITEM          │
│ METHOD │         │                                  │ (e.g. /USERS/123)      │
├────────┼─────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│ POST   │ Create  │ 201 (Created), 'Location'        │ Avoid using POST       │
│        │         │ with header link to /users/{id}  │ on single resource     │
│        │         │ containing new ID.               │                        │
├────────┼─────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│ GET    │ Read    │ 200 (OK), list of users. Use     │ 200 (OK), single user  │
│        │         │ pagination, sorting and          │ 404 (Not Found), If ID │
│        │         │ filtering to navigate big lists. │ not found or invalid.  │
├────────┼─────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│ PUT    │ Update/ │ 404 (Not Found), unless you want │ 200 (OK), or 204 (No   │
│        │ Replace │ to update every resource in the  │ Content). Use 404 (Not │
│        │         │ entire collection of resource.   │ Found). If ID not      │
│        │         │                                  │ found or invalid.      │
├────────┼─────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│ PATCH  │ Partial │ 404 (Not Found), unless you want │ 200 (OK), or 204 (No   │
│        │ Update/ │ to modify the collection itself. │ Content). Use 404 (Not │
│        │ Modify  │                                  │ Found). If ID not      │
│        │         │                                  │ found or invalid.      │
├────────┼─────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│ DELETE │ Delete  │ 404 (Not Found), unless you want │ 200 (OK), 404 (Not     │
│        │         │ to delete the whole collection - │ Fpund). If ID not      │
│        │         │ use with caution.                │ found or invalid       │
└────────┴─────────┴──────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the basic rules to use http method,

GET : When you need to fetch or retrive information

POST : When You need to create or insert information

PUT  : When you need to update existing record

For more information you can use this link.

https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer by Lokesh in reference to Laravel.
"index" method uses GET REQUEST as it retrieves records from the database.
"store" method uses POST REQUEST as it stores records in the database.
"update" method uses PUT REQUEST as it updates record in the database.
"show" method uses GET REQUEST as it retrieves single record from the database.
"delete" method uses DELETE REQUEST as it retrieves single record from the database.

Therefore you would want to use POST/PUT REQUEST if you want to change the record in the database. While toggling the status, the standard option is to use PUT, as your are updating a record.